# Could I replace the antenna of a USB dongle with a RP-SMA connector?

Tags: antenna

I'm looking to replace something like this antenna shown:[image]

with an RP-SMA connector. Would this work and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: Not readily in any sort of proper way. Just buy one with an antenna connector.  There are many online writeups explaining which are Linux/Pi compatible if the embossing on that cover is relevant to you.

Comment: Why RP? That's just going to be more difficult to source, probably more expensive, with no technical benefit.

Comment: the driver is expecting that specific antenna, you need an output designed for externals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would work. You would do it by desoldering or clipping the on board one and soldering on the new pigtail. That's it.

As others note, it may not work as well as the designed on. But it does work for many people. I've replaced a pcb trace antenna with a wired one with great results myself. Your mileage may vary, and be prepared to undo it or replace the device if you get bad results.

Comment: Might not work very well if there is a matching network or similar on the board